# Rails synchronise with S3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Does anyone know of a way to synchronise an S3 bucket with rails?

Basically what I would like is a tool that recognised when a file on s3 was added, renamed, or moved (modified) and be able to relay data about the changes to my web application so that I can update my database with the new changes.

If not a tool to do this directly, what would be the best thing to use to interface with S3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

S3 being an Object store, operations such as rename and modify are not directly possible. For example, rename is combination of

```
delete A + copy B (where A is the old name and B is the new name)
```

Modify is also similar. It is a combination of

```
delete A + copy A (where A is the old and new name. However s3 can preserve older versions of A)
```

You can enable logging on your s3 bucket. Then download the logs periodically, parse it for the items you are interested in, and update your local metadata.

See Documentation: [S3 Access Logging](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ServerLogs.html)